How can I load swiftly and asynchronously a pandas data frame into a PostGreSQL DB with SQL Alchemy?
My data frame has the same structure as the table in the DB. I used this function for the task until now:
async def upload_table_to_postgres_db(
    session: AsyncSession, data: pd.DataFrame, table_name: str
) -> None:
    """Uploads data to postgresDB."""
    conn = await session.connection()
    await conn.run_sync(
        lambda sync_conn, data=data: data.to_sql(
            name=table_name,
            con=sync_conn,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False,
            chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE,
            method=postgres_upsert,
        ),
    )
    await session.commit()

The issue with that function is, that it requires a sync connection for pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(). I have to manage quite large uploads and this function will block my API while uploading which I want to impede. If the solution is to chunk the data frame manually and write SQL into SQLAlchemy.text so be it. Does someone know a good solution for this problem? What also would be super nice is if I could send all chunks "at once" and let the API manage the order.
